# image unable to load when @ReguestMapping is included

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application and this is what happens, when I include @RequestMapping images and the dropdown menu are failing to load. but when I comment it out everything just working fine and write the URL without the request mapping path it works just fine. what would be the problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpServletResponse` :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image-manual-response", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/images/image-example.jpg");
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

check the documentation :

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data